# Is there a performance improvements over using the GetDC approach instead of the others?

Tags: c++, mfc, statusbar

Is there any benefits in using this code:

```
CClientDC dc(nullptr);
HFONT hFont = (HFONT)m_StatusBar.SendMessage(WM_GETFONT);
HGDIOBJ hOldFont = nullptr;
if (hFont != nullptr)
    hOldFont = dc.SelectObject(hFont);
cxNewWidth = dc.GetTextExtent(strCalendar).cx + kStatusBarIconWidth;
```

Or this code:

```
CClientDC dc(nullptr);
CFont *pFont = m_StatusBar.GetFont();
if (pFont != nullptr)
    dc.SelectObject(pFont);
cxNewWidth = dc.GetTextExtent(strCalendar).cx + kStatusBarIconWidth;
```

Or:

```
CDC *pDC = m_StatusBar.GetDC();
cxNewWidth = pDC->GetTextExtent(strCalendar).cx + kStatusBarIconWidth;
```

Comment: IDK, ... maybe an IC would be a better / more lightweight choice here than a DC since you only want to query some info? CDC dc; dc.CreateIC(_T("display"), NULL, NULL, NULL); But as commented elsewhere, it's highly unlikely this is your performance bottleneck. If it is, you might consider caching the value for calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and second code samples are identical. The documentation for [CWnd::GetFont](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getfont) explains, how it is implemented:

> Sends the WM_GETFONT message to the window to retrieve the current font.

The third code snippet is different from the previous ones in that it queries the control for a device context. What [CWnd::GetDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getdc) returns depends how the particular window class was registered. In the most common case, it will return the *"common device context"*:

> For common device contexts, `GetDC` assigns default attributes to the context each time it is retrieved.

In other words, in this case the device context you are retrieving may or may not have the desired font selected into it. As a general rule you should not rely on there being any particular graphics object selected into it.

None of the operations are inherently expensive. You should profile your code to find out, where it spends most of its time. The code posted likely isn't going to show up.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to retrieve the client DC of the `m_StatusBar`, then

```
CClientDC dc(m_StatusBar);
```

is the correct way to do it. This way you already have the correctly sized bitmap selected into the DC and you should probably be able to save GetFont(), too.
Retrieving the DC of some top level window using `ClientDC(nullptr);` and then selecting the font of the `m_StatusBar` into it seems wrong to me.

For the performance:
The `GetDC()` approach allocates a new DC each time it is called. Therefore you must supply `ReleaseDC()` for each of the `GetDC()` calls.
The CClientDC object just wraps `GetDC()` and `ReleaseDC()` in a class constructor and destructor. On the one side this is more convenient, on the other side the performance of the ClientDC approach is a tiny little worse than using `GetDC()` and `ReleaseDC()` directly due to the creation and destruction of a class instance. However, this is negligible.